# Type-GraphQL: Allow document owner and admin/moderator access with the @Authorized() decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, typegraphql

**Details**

I am using type-graphql and are trying to restrict data access or actions for a specific group of users with the `@Authorized()` decorator and a custom auth checker as a guard. Everything is working and access is blocked/allowed appropriately according to the decorator.

**Problem**

I want the owner/author of the document to be able to edit/delete it even if its marked with `@Authorized(["MODERATOR", "ADMIN"])` optionally I could mark it with something like `@Authorized(["OWNER", "MODERATOR", "ADMIN"])` if that makes it easier to implement.

As far as I know I dont have any information as to what Model/document the user is trying to access in the auth checker only the arguments of the mutation. In other words I have the ID of what they want to access but, not the Model it belongs to.

**Question**

Is there any way I can check if the user owns the document in the auth checker or will I have to mark it as `@Authorized()` and check if the user owns the document or is an admin/moderator in every mutation/query?

**Code**

index.d.ts

```js
declare module "type-graphql" {
    function Authorized(): MethodAndPropDecorator;
    function Authorized(roles: AccessLevels[]): MethodAndPropDecorator;
    function Authorized(...roles: AccessLevels[]): MethodAndPropDecorator;
}
```

types.ts

```js
type AccessLevels = "MODERATOR" | "ADMIN";
```

authChecker.ts

```js
const authChecker: AuthChecker<{ user: User | null }, AccessLevels> = ({ context }, roles): boolean => {
    if (!context.user) {
        return false;
    }

    if (roles.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    if (context.user.accessLevel > 0 && roles.includes("MODERATOR")) {
        return true;
    }

    return context.user.accessLevel > 1 && roles.includes("ADMIN");
};
```

EstablishmentResolver.ts

```js
@Authorized(["MODERATOR", "ADMIN"])
@Mutation(() => EstablishmentType, { description: "Deletes a establishment by ID" })
async deleteEstablishment(@Args() { id }: EstablishmentIdArg): Promise<Establishment> {
    const establishment = await Establishment.findOne({ where: { id } });

    if (!establishment) {
        throw new Error("Establishment does not exist");
    }

    await establishment.destroy();

    return establishment;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to modify the signature and logic to allow passing a callback into the decorator, that will resolve the "owner" condition:

```
@ObjectType
class User {
  @Authorized({ 
    roles: ["MODERATOR", "ADMIN"],
    owner: ({ root, context }) => {
      return root.id === context.user.id;
    },
  })
  @Field()
  email: string;
}
```

Be aware that you can't always do that inside the authChecker or middleware as they run before your resolver code, so in case of `deleteEstablishment` there's no universal way to match `establishmentId` with `user.id` to detect if it's an owner or not.

Comment: How would one "modify the signature"? As far as I can see this would mean rewriting multiple functions of the library yourself, as not only `Authorized`, but also the `AuthChecker` type depend on the function's signature. Shouldn't there be a way to extend the `Authorized` decorator with ownership-authorization without having to rewrite core functionality?